# Labelling multiple lines of equations with a single label

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, labels

[image: I want to latex that part 14.5 with labelling , but couldn't do it after try it several hours. It will be great if someone can help me]

I want to latex that equation 14.5. With labelling. But couldn't do it for several hours. So Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please show us what you try so far. this can be easily solved with `alegned` environment` form `amsmath` package encapsulated in `equation`  or use `array` inside `equation` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amsmath` package provides the `split` environment to let you achieve your formatting objective.

To give you a sense of what's involved:

- In the preamble of your LaTeX document, be sure to load either the `amsmath` package or a package -- such as `mathtools` -- which loads the `amsmath` package.
- In the body of the document, wrap a `split` environment inside an ordinary `equation` environment:

  ```
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  ... &= 0 \\
  ... &= 0 \\
  &\vdots \\
  ... &= 0 
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  ```

That's all there is to it.

If you would like to learn more about the many useful multi-line equation environments provided by the `amsmath` package, you should open a command window and type

```
texdoc amsmath
```

to bring up the user guide of the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I am learning latex for the first time. So had no idea about it. Thanks so much.